# React handle classNames on elements

Tags: reactjs

I have react app and also have list of cards. Every card is in div and it shows small portion of content of the div. When you click on the div it should expand and show all content. That i can do it with adding more one className to the div that is expanded. So how it is proparly to this in react.

```
<div className="card" onClick={?}>
    card conten
<div>
```

The point is i will have a lits of cards and i cant handle this with useState(). I thinks i should use somthing like:

```
e.target.classList.add("expandCard")
```

but i am not sure is that the right way to react handle the changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to keep an expanded state in each card, and show the content if it is expanded. Also you can apply a different class conditionally if it is expanded.

You can get an idea from this code:

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [cards, setCards] = useState([
    {
      id: 1,
      title: "title 1",
      content: "content 1"
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      title: "title 2",
      content: "content 2"
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      title: "title 3",
      content: "content 3"
    }
  ]);

  return (
    <div>
      {cards.map((card) => (
        <Card key={card.id} title={card.title}>
          {card.content}
        </Card>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

function Card({ children, title }) {
  const [expanded, setExpanded] = useState(false);
  return (
    <div className={`Card ${expanded ? "expandCard" : ""}`}>
      <h1>{title}</h1>
      <button onClick={() => setExpanded((prev) => !prev)}>Show Content</button>
      {expanded && <p>{children}</p>}
    </div>
  );
}
```

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-parm-2k9vxc?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Ou I started the problem from different direction, maybe because of that i didn't see the solution. It helps me alot. Thanks.